# PHP : wp_nav_menu adding icons

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, menu

How can I do this:
I want to create menu using wp_nav_menu() and to customize it's output html a little. I want to put `< i >` in link `< a >` inside every `< li >` item of the menu.

I know that I can acomplish this using background-image of `< li >` items in css, but my goal is to use font icons inside navigation.

I also know that in order to acomplish this we can use walker function inside `wp_nav_menu()`or use `wp_get_nav_menu_object()` function, but I simply can't make it right to work.

Comment: I found the walker parameter approach to be way to complex for something so easy. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079190/add-featured-image-to-wp-nav-menu-items/26079191

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the `before` or the `link_before` options?

`before` will output before the `<a>` and `link_before` will output inside the `<a>` before the text.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

```php
$settings = array(
     'before' => '<i class="icon"></i>',
     'link_before' => '<i class="icon"></i>'
);

wp_nav_menu( $settings );
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `wp walker` function and insert `wp menu description` there. Explaining more below -

Just put this code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
class fluent_themes_custom_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

private $blog_sidebar_pos = "";
// add classes to ul sub-menus
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array() ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
        'dropdown-menu',
        ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? '' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html

    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}

// add main/sub classes to li's and links
 function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array(), $id = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;
    $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

    // depth dependent classes
    $depth_classes = array(
        ( $depth == 0 ? '' : '' ), //class for the top level menu which got sub-menu
        ( $depth >=1 ? '' : 'dropdown' ), //class for the level-1 sub-menu which got level-2 sub-menu
        ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ), //class for the level-2 sub-menu which got level-3 sub-menu
        ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
        'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
    );
    $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

    // passed classes
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

    // build html
    $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

    // link attributes
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    //$attributes .= ' class="' . ( $depth > 0 ? '' : '' ) . '"';

    // Check if menu item is in main menu
    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id)
                            FROM wp_postmeta
                            WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent'
                            AND meta_value='".$item->ID."'");

    if ( $depth == 0 && $has_children > 0  ) {
        // These lines adds your custom class and attribute
        $attributes .= ' class="dropdown-toggle"';
        $attributes .= ' data-toggle="dropdown"';
        $attributes .= ' data-hover="dropdown"';
        $attributes .= ' data-animations="fadeInUp"';
    }
    $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<i class="fa '.esc_attr( $item->description ).'" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $description.$args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after; //If you want the description to be output after <a>
    //$item_output .= $description.$args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after; //If you want the description to be output before </a>

    // Add the caret if menu level is 0
    if ( $depth == 0 && $has_children > 0  ) {
        $item_output .= ' &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>';
    }

    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    // build html
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args, $id );
}
} //End Walker_Nav_Menu
```

See this line:

```
$description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<i class="fa '.esc_attr( $item->description ).'" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : '';
```

And this line:

```
$item_output .= $description.$args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
```

Here you see **$item->desctiption** is a variable. For example: if you put **fa-user** as menu item description of a menu. The html output of the above line will be:

The full html output of the menu will be something like this:

```
<ul class="top-nav nav-right">
                    <li class="dropdown"> 
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" data-animations="fadeInUp">
                            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>My Profile
                             <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-bargraph"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-gears"></i> Profile Setting</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-heart"></i> Questions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-lock"></i> Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
```

However, here is your wp nav menu code in your header.php file or in any other theme files:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location'  => 'top_bar_login','container'  => false,'container_id'  => '','conatiner_class' => '','menu_class'  => 'top-nav nav-right','echo'  => true,'items_wrap'  => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>','depth'  => 10, 'walker' => new fluent_themes_custom_walker_nav_menu) );
```

If you are not sure where is the description of wordpress menu, or you want more details with screenshot. You can read this article [Adding Different Icons To Different Items Of WP Nav Menu](http://fluentthemes.com/adding-different-icons-different-items-wp-nav-menu/)

Answer (score 1):

I'am also trying to add icons in my menu.

I've tried `before` and `link_before` options but I did't find the way to get any item's variables inside these args.

My aim is to get the following output using `Title Attribute` set in `Custom Link` from `Customize Menus`

```
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-30"> 
    <a title="social-facebook" href="http://facebook.com"> 
         <i class="fi-social-facebook"></i>Facebook Page 
    </a>
</li> 

<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-30"> 
    <a title="social-google-plus+" href="http://plus.google.com"> 
        <i class="fi-social-google-plus"></i>Google+ Page 
    </a>
</li>
```

I've also check the other answer but I don't know how to add thumbnails in the `Custom Link` of the `Customize Menus`.

Answer (score 0):

paste code to the page where you output your nav

```
<?php
            wp_nav_menu(
                            array(
                                     'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                      'container' => false,
                                      'walker' => new my_nav_walker()
                                   )
                                 );
  ?>
```

and then call walker.php in functions.php

```
require get_template_directory().'/inc/walker.php';
```

copy class Walker_Nav_Menu in class-walker-nav-menu.php from wp-includes folder
change Walker_Nav_Menu class to my_nav_walker

and then inside function start_el of my_nav_walker class 
make a variable called $description as:

```
    $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<i class="fa '.esc_attr( $item->description ).'" ></i>' : '';
```

Paste this code inside start_el function of my_nav_walker class

```
$item_output = $args->before;
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
$item_output .= $description.$args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
$item_output .= '</a>';
$item_output .= $args->after;
```

if you add fa-user in description of menu item from backend user icon appear between a href tag inside li